# How to pass std::sqrt as an argument

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to create a generic function `Foo` that will accept an argument and Op what will be applied to it.

```
template <template<class> class Op>   
float foo(float boo) {
    return Op(boo);
}

template <template<class> class Op>   
float foo(float a, float b) {
    return Op(a, b);
}

void caller() {
    float boo = 2.3;
    auto res1 = foo<std::plus>(boo, boo); // works
    auto res2 = foo<std::sqrt>(boo); // fail. error: no instance of overloaded function.
    auto res3 = foo<std::exp>(boo); // fail. error: no instance of overloaded function
}
```

I think it's related that [std::sqrt](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt) is

> "A set of overloads or a function template accepting an argument of
> any integral type. "

while [std::plus](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) is

> Function object for performing addition.

How do I pass `std::sqrt` and `std::exp` to `foo`?

Comment: Can you post please a mcve? As this code does not compile because the second and the third definitions are the same.

Comment: I wonder what are you trying to achieve? After all `std::plus` is a class which represents binary function and `std::sqrt` is unary function. So IMO this question is incorrectly stated and suffers from [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Sorry, updated the example. I was trying to show that no mater on how Op is used, i can't pass std::sqrt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass an overload set as a template argument. A simple workaround could be to wrap `sqrt` and `exp` into functors with a templated `operator()`:

```
struct Sqrt {
    template<class T>
    T operator()(T t) const { return std::sqrt(t); }
};

struct Exp {
    template<class T>
    T operator()(T t) const { return std::exp(t); }
};
```

Then the following will work

```
    auto res2 = foo<Sqrt>(boo);
    auto res3 = foo<Exp>(boo);
```

Answer (score 3):

As you've identified, the problem is that your template expects a *type* (because that's how you've written it), and though `std::plus` is a type (a functor), `std::sqrt` is a function.

It's hard to give a concrete solution for your problem, because you never showed your usage of `Op`.

But, generally, this is easy to do with an `auto` template parameter:

```
template <auto Op>
float foo(const float boo) {
    return Op(boo);
}
```

If your version of C++ is too old, you'll need to add a version that takes a function pointer instead.

Comment: Even with `auto` parameters, I'm pretty sure passing `&std::sqrt` would result in ambiguities since there are 3 possible overloads it may refer to -- so it would need to be distinctly identified with a `static_cast` to the appropriate function pointer type

Answer (score 3):

`std::sqrt` is an overloaded function, not a type. A simple fix would be to write a generic lambda that wraps `std::sqrt`, and then use its type when calling `foo`, like this:

```
auto sqrt = [](auto n) { return std::sqrt(n); };
auto res2 = foo<decltype(sqrt)>(boo); // ok
```

And you can do the same for `std::exp`.

Whether this is a good fix depends on how you want to use the `Op` parameter, which is not clear from the question.